# Kiwi not calling stubbed class method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, testing, kiwi

I'm writing some Kiwi specs to test the authentication system in my app, specifically loading a set of stored credentials. The example works by stubbing methods in `NSUserDefaults` and `SSKeychain` to return fixed data, which the authentication class then uses to configure my API client. The code looks something like this:

```
it(@"authenticates the client with saved credentials", ^{
    [NSUserDefaults stub:@selector(standardUserDefaults) andReturn:@{MoneyBrilliantActiveAccountKey: @"mock@example.com"}];
    [SSKeychain stub:@selector(passwordForService:account:) andReturn:@"fooBarBaz"];

    [[mockRequestSerializer should] receive:@selector(setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:) withCount:2];

    MyAuthManager *newAuthManager = [[MyAuthManager alloc] initWithAPIClient:mockAPIClient];
    [[theValue([newAuthManager isAuthenticated]) should] beNo];
    [[theValue([newAuthManager authenticateClientWithSavedCredentials]) should] beYes];
    [[theValue([newAuthManager isAuthenticated]) should] beYes];
});
```

However, this example fails, and I've managed to track the reason why down to my stubbed implementation of `+passwordForService:account:` not being called on `SSKeychain`.

Is there something obvious I'm missing that would prevent this stub from being called?

Comment: Are you stubbing the SSKeychain in other parts of the tests also? Multiple stubs of class methods might bring you problems, myself I try to avoid as much as possible stubs for class methods.